# Cant get all value from Firebase in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, object, firebase-realtime-database, getvalue

I have some problem about reading value in Firebase Database,
This is structure of Realtime Database, sorry I wasn't allowed to embedded picture:

- LampController

  - Schedule

    - TimeEnd: "5:30"
    - TimeStart: "21:15"
    - isActive: true

This is my Object class, also contains Constructor, Getter and Setter:

```
public class ScheduleObject {
    private String TimeEnd;
    private String TimeStart;
    private Boolean isActive;

    ...
}
```

When I use dataSnapshot.getValue(ScheduleObject.class), I will get values from TimeEnd and TimeStart but isActive is always return null. Seem like it didn't get the value on Firebase but I don't know why?

```
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                scheduleObject = new ScheduleObject();
                scheduleObject = dataSnapshot.getValue(ScheduleObject.class);
            }
        }
```

Only when I use dataSnapshot.child("isActive").getValue(Boolean.class) its will return value from Firebase.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

option 1) if your boolean field is named as isActive, then the getter must be named as isIsActive() or getIsActive()

option 2) if you want a getter isActive, the field name would be active only